# Web scraping without Javascript in Python using requests

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, python-requests

So, I'm making a Python script, that gets a webpages content and compares it to a previously saved version to see if the webpage has changed. I'm getting the raw content using this method:

```
def getcontent(url):
    str = requests.get(url)
    str = str.text
    return(str)
```

after that I'm doing some cleaning up of the content and quote escaping and such, but that's irrelevant. The issue I keep running into, is, that the webpage has got some JavaScript code, that generates a unique key that my method downloads. Each time you grab the webpage content, the key is different. I have zero idea what that key is for. The issue is, that if the key is different, the new content, and the saved content aren't identical.

How can I disable JavaScript from running when I request a webpage?

Comment: A request should not run javascript. I don't think there is anything you can do from that perspective. Perhaps you can check everything except for the unique key?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to prevent serverside code from doing what serverside code does.... The best you can do is clean the data to prevent false diffs. To that point it very well could be javascript doing it, but serverside (such as node.js). But requests.get does not execute any client-side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token is generated server-side and can be used for various reasons (for example CSRF-token)

The token will always be in the content of your response, there is no JavaScript needed for that.

You should find a way to ignore / remove the token.